# EC2 Auto Scaling terminates the instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling is terminating the instances of Elastic Beanstalks we are using.  Auto Scaling events says that it was taken out of service in response to a user request. However, nobody in our team did anything, and we are trying to understand the reason behind this. Did anyone experience something like this? Thank you.

Edit: The current capacity configuration:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Dss.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpc4I.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Di1.png)

Comment: How often is it terminating? Have you confirmed the load balancer health checks are passing?

Comment: For one instance, it happens every 2 weeks. For the other one, it happens every month.

Comment: What Scaling Policies are associated with the Auto Scaling group?

Comment: We haven't created Scaling Policies. So I think we are using default ones. Also, these are internal test servers, so we do not have a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

For the Elastic Beanstalk application, if you check "Configuration - Capacity", you will find the Max and Min instance number, you can test if you set both Max and Min to 1 instance, and wait couple of day to see if the instance is replaced (check the instance ID is not changed).

And also make sure the scaling triggers section has the right configuration, this might be the source of your instance termination.

Comment: The desired/min/max values are set to 1 in the current configuration. I couldn't see any scaling triggers section in the capacity section.

Comment: The configuration has 3 major sections: Auto Scaling Group,  Scaling triggers and Time-based scaling.  it is in the Congiruation but not a part of capacity section.

Comment: We have 2 sections: Auto Scaling Group and Time-based scaling. I added the ss.